Using FSIN through inline-assembly
I want to use x87's FSIN through gcc's / clang's inline assembly. How would a sin()-function using an __asm__-block internally for that look like with a 64 bit double parameter ? Using __builtin_sin() didn't help since this directly branches to a libary function.

Are you looking for something like this: https://pastebin.com/KmpDGbYY

Loading double to FPU with GCC (Inline assembler) shows an inefficient way that uses fld / fstp inside the asm statement, instead of using a constraint for st0 to let the compiler worry about loading and storing, letting it use the value in st0 for other FP math.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Floating-Point-asm-Operands for how to write an asm statement wrapping a single instruction that just updates st0

@PeterCordes: A FLD / STP pair wouldnt hurt much with an instruction taking up to 200 clock cycles on my Zen4-CPU.

@EdisonvonMyosotis: True, although you could also say there's no point wasting static code-size on something that's not going to be fast anyway.  And since latency is so high, OoO exec will have a hard time hiding it, so adding another maybe 7 cycles for a store/reload is bad.  (If it was avoidable, e.g. if the value was the result of an x87 computation, perhaps with long double.  If it was the result of an SSE computation, it has to get stored/reloaded anyway.)

Was the answer of any use? If it was a solution you should consider accepting an answer to mark this question for future readers. I noticed in your question history that you haven't accepted any other answers. You can read more about how to accept an answer and why it is beneficial here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768 .

Does the  -ffast-math command line option help?

GCC's extended inline assembly can use the FPU stack for passing parameters in and out. The GCC documentation has a list of the Machine Constraints for the x86. In particular:

t
Top of 80387 floating-point stack (%st(0)).
u
Second from top of 80387 floating-point stack (%st(1))

The fsin instruction takes an input on the top of the FPU stack (st(0)) and returns the result on the top of the FPU stack. We can use an output constraint of =t to return the top of the stack to a local variable and use the same (0th or 0) constraint for the input. The following code should assemble as both 32-bit and 64-bit code:
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
double x87_sin (double x)
{
    double sinval;
 
    asm ("fsin" : "=t" (sinval) : "0" (x));
    return sinval;
}
 
int main(void)
{
    double x = 45.0*M_PI/180.0;
    printf ("%f\n", x87_sin(x));
    return 0;
}

